# Stored Procedure with Single Int (ID) Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to learn how to create and use SQL Server stored procedures, and I am finding that every example out there, uses `varchar(xx)` as the parameters, and never an `int`, which is what would be used if for example, you wanted to search on an ID value to select a specific record, such as in the first code example.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetApplicationStartData 
    @CompanyID int(1)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM ApplicationStartData 
    WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID
GO
```

Using this code, when it is executed, the following error occurs:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure GetApplicationStartData, Line 7
> Must declare the scalar variable "@CompanyID"

Following is an example from the Microsoft website:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.uspGetEmployeesTest2   
    @LastName nvarchar(50),   
    @FirstName nvarchar(50)   
AS   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Department  
    FROM HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartmentHistory  
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName  
      AND EndDate IS NULL;  
GO
```

Here is a snippet of the design of the `ApplicationStartData` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationStartData]
(
    [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PrimaryDomainName] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CompanyName] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [CompanyAddress1] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [CompanyAddress2] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [CompanyCity] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CompanyState] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [CompanyZIP] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [CompanyPhone1] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CompanyPhone2] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CompanyPhone3] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CompanyFax] [varchar](15) NULL,
    ... and 40 more columns
```

How is this accomplished?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: `int(1)` is invalid in SQL Server. There's no length specifier on the `int` type.

Comment: Thank you Dale.  Yes, I do understand how this site works, and thank you very much for your answers.  They came in so quickly, that I didn't have an opportunity to react just yet.  I was editing my question to include more information.

Comment: Thank you Damien.  That is correct.  However, I am trying to use an int ID in a stored procedure, same as if one would perform the following:

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM ApplicationStartData Where CompanyID = 1"

Comment: If I remove the length specifier, the same error occurs.

Comment: Compare the name of your input parameter with the parameter in your query... they are not the same.

Comment: Your stored procedure `GetApplicationStartData` defines a parameter **@CustomerID** - but in the code of that procedure, you reference **@CompanyID** (which really doesn't exist in the list of parameters!) .......

Comment: You are correct.  Thank you very much!  It's 1:00AM here and my tired eyes did not see that.

Comment: Please note that you're under *no obligation* to vote or accept Answers on your Questions. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hello Scrattle.  Thank you for your comment.  I was indeed fairly confused by what happened throughout this discussion, and then with the question being closed due to it being "caused by a typo."  This is actually only partly true, what with the cause of the question still being of concern, since all examples out on the Internet only using nvarchar or varchar parameters.  Therefore, it wasn't clear how one would declare an int parameter, but via this question, and the comments above, it now is clear.  And I was never able to accept the answer, due to it being closed.  All a bit confusing.

Comment: As far as I can see there are no Answers on this post though. Comments are not Answers :) The closure due to the typo seems to me to have been inspired by the CustomerID/CompanyID confusion, which I'd presume isn't a mistake others are likely to make. On a side note: I did not get pinged by your last comment, but only happened upon your post again by chance. To ping a users use @ and a few of the characters of their username to see the tab-completion, like @PaulScott Misspelling the username will also not ping them ;)

Comment: My general advice is that once someone has taken the time to go through your profile and comment on your accept/vote behaviour on the site, then just disengage. Voting, in my opinion, should not be a "Thank you for taking your time" but "This is good". Also, if you want to make the best of the site, you should probably spend some time reading the pages of the [Help Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q66PI.png).

Comment: @Scratte.  I am going to continue to thank you and anybody else for taking the time to discuss anything that I happen to put up on this site.  I believe it to be a simple, civil gesture, often missing in today's society.  I do need to again state that if the simple typo had NOT been in the question, then my original issue would have remained, and eventually been answered.  Yes, it's a typo, "which isn't a mistake that others are likely to make", but once the typo was fixed, the original issue remained.  I figured it out, but wasn't able to answer the question because it was closed.

Comment: @Scratte.  Ran out of characters.  I actually do not understand your second comment, especially the "disengage" part.  However, I have taken a great deal of time reading the pages of the Help Center in the past.  In all fairness, I've learned a lot more from users such as yourself, than from the Help Center.

Comment: @PaulScott With "disengage" I meant that if you feel a user is pressuring you or not being helpful, then you're in your right to not continue any conversation or other interaction with them. You could consider editing your post *and* raising a custom flag politely asking for this long comment trail be completely removed due to it not being relevant anymore. And hope that your edit make users want to reopen it. I'm not overly optimistic though as some users think that what they consider to be simple Questions don't belong here. Note: I don't agree with that.

Comment: @Scratte.  I will do that.  You're absolutely correct, and I also do not agree with the "Question too simple to be here" concept.  I have seen questions that are so incredibly simple, as to seem obvious, but what is obvious to one, is not to another.  After all, this is just a bunch of text.  No harm done.

Comment: @Scratte.  Unfortunately, I cannot add a custom tag.  It requires a reputation of 1500.  Thank you again for all of your help.  Very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which new tag you wanted to add to your Question. Creating tags should be done with care, as tags are often removed from posts if users feel they do not add any value, only for the tag itself to be deleted. I only mentioned raising a custom *flag* to have the comment trail removed. It asks you to type in an explanation of what your concern or request is. It will be handled by on of the few [moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) of the site, who will mark your flag either helpful or declined depending on whether they agree with you :)

Comment: However for this post to go into the reopen-queue, you need to make an edit to it *after* if was closed, which I can't see was done, so I do not expect it to be in line for a second evaluation. Note that users in the reopen-queue will see the before and after revisions of your edit, which scews the result if you made substantial edits prior to your post being closed. (As a side note you only get the opportunity to get your post into the reopen-queue on the *first* edit after your post was closed. Once the post has been re-evaluated, no edits will push it in again)

Comment: @Scratte.  I must be losing my eyesight.  I saw "flag" as "tag" for some reason.  Thank you again.